# Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line (KendoUI)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have problem in script part of MVC.

```
<script>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id= #= userid # })
<script>
```

When I write `@`, `#` gives error. With KendoUI Grid (opensource), I can get table id using `#= userid #` . So I need to get this ID. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be problem in merging client side logic and backend.

```
@Html.ActionLink()
```

This is asp.net backend code, it generates before client side logic run, but

```
#= userid #
```

is client side code, and it run in browser by Kendo Grid system.

In this case you try run backend generator through client side Kendo Grid, what is impossible.

To fix this problem and had functionality that you want, you need or pass userid across backend variable like 
`@userId`, or paste simple html code like

```
<a href="http://url" id="#= userid #">text</a>
```